Cannot find module './$types.js' or its corresponding type declarations
I am developing a SvelteKit codebase in Visual Studio Code. I am using Svelte plugin for Visual Studio Code.
For load(), POST(), GET(), et. Visual Studio Code linter complains:
Cannot find module './$types.js' or its corresponding type declarations. (this likely means that SvelteKit's type generation didn't run yet - try running it by executing 'npm run dev' or 'npm run build')ts(2307)




This is an old codebase
I am running npm run dev and also have run npm run build
I also run the quick before to install "@types/node": "^20.12.7" - no more quick fixes available

What could be wrong with the configuration, and how to configure Visual Studio Code to correctly resolve function signatures for SvelteKit?

there is not enough info here to reproduce the problem. please add a [mre]. that includes minimal code, minimal package.json, minimal .vscode/settings.json, version numbers of relevant VS Code extensions, and exact version numbers of dependency packages from running npm list, and any other relevant (,minimal) svelte project configuration.
